# SQL query to get the row of data which should not exist in other table when combining three table

Tags: mysql, sql

Thanks everybody in advance. Actually I am using mysql database. I have three tables courses, exams and prices. I need a row of data when comparing courses, exams and prices tables where the data of prices table should not exist in exams table when passing course table id, this $courseId I am passing from loop.

I have written a SQL query like this

```
select e.*, cs.* FROM exams e 
left join courses cs on e.course_id = cs.id 
left join prices p on e.course_id = p.course_id 
where cs.id = '$courseId' AND p.course_id IS NULL
```

but it's not working. Please anyone guide me.

**Courses** table

```
id | name
1  | ITIL Foundation
2  | PMP
3  | CAPM
```

**Exams** table

```
 id     username    course_id
 1      58            1
 2      58            2
 3      58            3
```

**Prices** table

```
 id     userid  course_id   price
  1     58         1        10
  2     58         2        20
```

I need a "exams" table row like this

**Exams** table

```
id  username    course_id
1       58            3
```

Comment: There's no **from table.....** in your query.....

Comment: `select e.*, cs.* from exams e left join courses cs ...`

Comment: ya i have edited my sql query

Answer (score -1):

try writing a sub-query to get the values of course_id from price table, then add a condition course_id not in (sub-query).

```
select e.*,cs.* from exams as e
left join courses as cs on e.course_id=cs.id
and where course_id not in (select course_id from prices);
```

i think this would work. i am just a beginner . forgive me if its wrong.

Comment: Leave out the `and` before the `where` and it should work. ;-). It should look like `select e.*,cs.* from exams as e
left join courses as cs on e.id=cs.id
where id not in (select course_id from prices)`